# Most reliable way to validate an uploaded file type in C# to prevent malicious, even if renamed to accepted file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, uploading

I read some articles about uploading files, people can upload malicious programs (php, exe,...) to attack the server and the website, what is the  reliable way to protect and avoid any danger for the website and our server. In my website, I need to allow my registered users to upload files like
**.doc, .txt, .pdf** extension files.
So any idea to validate to uploaded file is in acceptable file format (even it is renamed)
Ideas in C# will appreciated.

Comment: even with the proper format, a doc or pdf can be malicious.

Comment: Some binary formats have "magic bytes" at the beginning to signal their kind of content regardless of the used file extension. Nevertheless a valid .pdf can also contain malicious code. All you can do is, run it through a virus scanner to check.

Comment: Too broad of a question for SO, sorry